# Generate notional dummy data in Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am trying to generate dummy test data in Foundries Pipeline builder but I can't seem to find any options on a new pipeline. What are the steps needed to generate notional data on a new pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate test data in Pipeline Builder you can go to Add Data, pick Enter Data Manually, then add columns in the left-hand sidebar, then pick the data types for each column, and then click "Generate Notional Data" in the upper right. From there, you can modify how the data is generated for each column.

I made a screen recording of this, but the file is too large to upload to StackOverflow/Imgur. You can view it [here](https://www.ontologize.com/blog/how-to-generate-notional-data-in-foundry-pipeline-builder).

Comment: Thank you for the screen recording. My account doesn't have the enter data manually option but I was able to follow the instructions in another account.